# Time machine stuck on Stopping... on mac os mojave

Tags: macos, time-machine, mojave

On my macbook pro laptop running Mac OS Mojave, Time machine menu item is stuck at Stopping... Can I have TM restart doing backups again. I would rather not restart my laptop as I have so many processes and VMs running right now. Is it safe to kill -9 the time machine background daemon? Thanks.